# Adjoint for real functions

Tags: real-analysis, lattice-orders, adjoint-functors, semicontinuous-functions

We want to find sufficient and necessary conditions for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be adjoints with the usual order in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e $$f(x)\leq y\;\Leftrightarrow\; x\leq g(y).$$

Hint: It is necessary that $f,g$ are lower semicontinuous and upper semicontinuous respectively, and of course they have to be nondecreasing functions. In addition, they said we need another sufficient condition.

I have no idea how to start, even I don't understand the hint.

Any hint or idea you can give me, I would be thankful.

Comment: It might be useful to know that right adjoints preserve limits and left adjoints preserve colimits (in 5he categorical sense, not analysis). You can translate this to continuity conditions in your setting.

Comment: @Nico Yeah, I thought the same, and I tried it, but I didn't understand how the limit in the categorical sense agreed with the usual definition of limit :/. I was thinking to take some sequences, however, it doesn't work either.